# What's the correct include order

Tags: c++, c, include, preprocessor, include-path

Got -1 on gerrit because I use following include order:

```
#include <aaa/b.h>
#include <aaa/d.h>
#include <aaa/f.h>
#include <aaa/h.h>
#include <aaa/bbb/c.h>
#include <aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/e.h>
#include <aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/a.h>
#include <aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/g.h>
```

My reviewer expect me to use following alphabetical (.h files ) order:

```
#include <aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/a.h>
#include <aaa/b.h>
#include <aaa/bbb/c.h>
#include <aaa/d.h>
#include <aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/e.h>
#include <aaa/f.h>
#include <aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/g.h>
#include <aaa/h.h>
```

Which order is correct? I'm sure that my way is much better but I got -1.

Comment: There is no such thing as "correct" include order in well written headers. And we can't tell if those are well written headers or not.

Comment: There's no "correct" order, you should follow the style of your group. Therefore, this question is off-topic as any answer would be based on opinions.

Comment: I'm not sure this is "primarily" opinion-based. The primary part of any answer ought to concentrate on the fact that well-written headers can be included in any order. And that's factual.

Comment: @Bathsheba "*I'm sure that my way is much better*" suggests the asker already knows it works in any order...

Answer (score 2):

Header files are normally written so you can include them in any order you like at the point of use. The C and C++ standard library headers conform to that principle.

If that's not the case, then the supporting documentation ought to say so.

Alpabeticisation is just an expression of the way your reviewer's mind is working, and I don't think it's particularly helpful.

For what it's worth I tend to put more "generic" inclusions higher up a list (e.g. `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` pretty much at the top).

Comment: I tend order from specific to generic to spot dependency issues earlier, but this is not a rule.

Answer (score 0):

I afraid your reviewers programming knowledge is low. My advice - do what he wants (usually as low your skills are as big ego is), but forget about the alphabetical order. Order has to be logical not alphabetical

Comment: *I afraid your reviewers programming knowledge is low* NO! He is working in a team. If the team has a style he needs to follow it. It is not the reviewers fault. I am sure both the parties involved here know that the headers inclusion order should not matter to the behavior. But notice that the question is about gerrit not programming.